# Vinaya non-offence complications?

Tags: vinaya

From suttacentral Parajika rules:

> "Non-offenses - There is no offense: **if it is unintentional**; if he
>   does not know; if he is not aiming at death; if he is insane; **if he
>   is the first offender**." [PJ 3](https://suttacentral.net/en/pi-tv-bu-vb-pj1)

What happens to unintentional second offenders? The ignorant/under-informed? If one kills unintentionally, but aware of the offence of killing, where does one stand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Patimokkha Rules
Translated & Explained
by Thanissaro Bhikkhu](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc1.pdf), on pages 49 through 50, uses the word "or" (not "and"):

> **Blanket exemptions**. In addition to bhikkhus who do not know they are
>   being assaulted or do not give their consent when they do know, the Vibhanga
>   states that there are four special categories of bhikkhus exempted from a penalty
>   under this rule: any bhikkhu who is insane, possessed by spirits, delirious with
>   pain, **or** the first offender(s) (in this case, Ven. Sudinna and the bhikkhu with the
>   monkey) whose actions prompted the Buddha to formulate the rule. The
>   Commentary defines as insane anyone who “goes about in an unseemly way,
>   with deranged perceptions, having cast away all sense of shame and 
>   50
>   compunction, not knowing whether he has transgressed major or minor training
>   rules.” It recognizes this as a medical condition, which it blames on the bile. A
>   bhikkhu under the influence of a severe psychosis-inducing drug would
>   apparently fall under this exemption, but one under the influence of a more
>   common intoxicant would not. As for spirit possession, the Commentary says
>   that this can happen either when spirits frighten one or when, by distracting one
>   with sensory images, they insert their hands into one’s heart by way of one’s
>   mouth (!). Whatever the cause, it notes that insane and possessed bhikkhus are
>   exempt from penalties they incur only when their perceptions are deranged
>   (“when their mindfulness is entirely forgotten and they don’t know what fire,
>   gold, excrement, and sandalwood are”) and not from any they incur during their
>   lucid moments. As for a bhikkhu delirious with pain, he is exempt from penalties
>   he incurs only during periods when the pain is so great that he does not know
>   what he is doing.
>
> These four categories are exempted from penalties under nearly all of the
>   rules, although the first offender for each rule is exempted only for the one time
>   he acted in such a way as to provoke the Buddha into formulating the rule. I will
>   only rarely mention these categories again, and—except where expressly stated
>   otherwise—the reader should bear them in mind as exempt in every case.

So I read that as saying that any one of the conditions is reason for it's being a non-offence; and that the only condition for exemption that's only applicable once is being a first offender.

On page 29 it says,

> If any of these factors is missing, the penalty changes. For instance, object: If
>   the bhikkhu kills a dog, the penalty is a pacittiya. Perception: If he cremates a
>   friend, thinking that the friend is dead, then even if the friend is actually alive but
>   severely comatose, the bhikkhu incurs no penalty. Intention: If he accidentally
>   drops a rock on a person standing below him, he incurs no penalty even if the
>   person dies. Effort: If he sees a person fall into the river but makes no effort to
>   save the person, he incurs no penalty even if the person drowns. Result: If he
>   tries to kill a person, but only succeeds in injuring him, he incurs a thullaccaya.

Pages 76 though 78 (which I won't quote here in full) discuss intention w.r.t. killing; briefly:

> The non-offense clauses state that there is no offense for a bhikkhu who acts
>   unintentionally, not knowing, or without aiming at death. In the Vinita-vatthu,
>   *unintentionally* is used to describe cases in which a bhikkhu acts accidentally, such
>   as dropping a poorly held stone, brick, or adze; removing a pestle from a shelf
>   and accidentally knocking off another one. *Not knowing* is used in cases in which
>   the bhikkhu deliberately does an action but without knowing that his action
>   could cause death. An example would be giving food to a friend not knowing
>   that it is poisoned. *Not aiming at death* is used in cases where the bhikkhu
>   deliberately does an action but does not intend that action to result in death.
>   Relevant examples include trying to help a bhikkhu who is choking on food by
>   slapping him on the back and inadvertently causing his death; telling a bhikkhu
>   to stand on a piece of scaffolding while helping with construction work, only to 
>   see the scaffolding collapse; describing the joys of heaven to an audience, only to
>   have a member of the audience decide to commit suicide in hopes of going there.
>
> Thus, to fulfill the factor of intention here, a bhikkhu must be acting
>   intentionally, knowingly, and aiming at death.

Page 78 suggests that acting when aware of danger might or might not count as intentional:

> In discussing the topic of pitfalls, the Commentary also treats the issue of
>   how much of an intention counts when setting up a situation that might cause
>   death. Specifically, it asks whether—while one is digging a hole for another
>   purpose—a passing thought that “this hole could kill anyone who fell into it”
>   would fulfil the factor of intention under this rule, or whether this factor would
>   be fulfilled only if the original purpose for digging the hole was to cause death.
>   The Commentary notes that opinions are divided on this point, but it sides with
>   the latter position.

Answer (score 1):

if it is unintentional = no physical effort;

if he does not know = such as sleeping;

if he is not aiming at death = very hard painful suffering, he can't realize anything else;

if he is insane = schizophrenia;

**if he is the first offender = just sudinna-bhikkhu, the first bhikkhu who have a sex, then buddha use his case as the cause to create the pathamaparajika-sikkhapada.**